# Show that the sequence $\left\{b_n\right\}:b_n=\frac{5n^2+2n-1}{3n^2-14}$ converges

Tags: limits

Show that the sequence $\left\{b_n\right\}:b_n=\dfrac{5n^2+2n-1}{3n^2-14}$ converges **(using Weierstrass theorem)**.

So we are supposed to show that $\{b_n\}$ is 1) monotonic and 2) bounded. It's usually easier to start by proving that the sequence is monotonic. The $(n+1)$th term is $$b_{n+1}=\dfrac{5(n+1)^2+2(n+1)-1}{3(n+1)^2-14}=\dfrac{5n^2+12n+6}{3n^2+6n-11}$$ Neither $b_{n+1}-b_n$, nor $\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ looks easy. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: What is Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: @WilliamM. Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @WilliamM.   It states that we're supposed to show that the sequence is monotonic and bonded for it to converges.

Comment: Dividing top and bottom by $n^2$ you can easily see that $b_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ large (say $n \geq 14$). Taking the derivative of $x \to \dfrac{5x^2+2x-1}{3x^2-14}$ will yield $\dfrac{-6x^2 + p(x)}{(3x^2 - 14)^2} \leq 0$ ($p$ is a polynomial of first degree) for all large $x.$ So, $b_n$ is non negative and eventually decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use brute force:

$$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{5n^2+12n+6}{3n^2+6n-11}-\frac{5n^2+2n-1}{3n^2-14}=-\frac{6 n^2 + 140 n + 95}{(3 n^2 - 14) (3 n^2 + 6 n - 11)}$$

So it easy to see that $b_{n+1}-b_n<0$ for $n\ge 3$

Also $b_n>0$ for the same $n\ge 3$, so $b_n$ is bounded as well, thus Weierstraß theorem applies.

Answer (score 0):

For fractions of 2 polynomials, the method is always the same: factor out the highest degree term in both numerator and denominator, and then apply standard limit results:$$\frac{5n^2+2n-1}{3n^2-14}=\frac{5n^2}{3n^2}\cdot\frac{1+\frac2{5n}-\frac1{5n^2}}{1-\frac{14}{3n^2}}=\frac53\cdot \frac{1+\frac2{5n}-\frac1{5n^2}}{1-\frac{14}{3n^2}}.$$
There shouldn't be any indeterminate form left in the second fraction. The same method applies to all fractions of two polynomials, and you do not need to study monotonicity/boundedness of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am just in the beginning of my course, so I have to study monotonicity/boundedness of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left|\dfrac{5n^{2}+2n-1}{3n^{2}-14}-\frac{5}{3}\right|=\left|\frac{15n^{2}+6n-3-15n^{2}+70}{3\left(3n^{2}-14\right)}\right|\le\left|\frac{6n+70}{3n^{2}-14}\right|\le\left|\frac{76n}{3n^{2}-14n}\right|=\frac{76}{3n-14}\le\varepsilon\Rightarrow \\76\le3n\varepsilon-14\varepsilon\Rightarrow76+14\varepsilon\le3n\varepsilon\Rightarrow\frac{76+14\varepsilon}{3\varepsilon}\le n $$
This is all true assuming $ 3n^2-14 $ is positive so we can take $ N_0=\max\left\{ \frac{76+14\varepsilon}{3\varepsilon},10\right\}  $ and then we found the limit.

Comment: It's $-15n^2+70$. Thank you!

Comment: my bad, but the same routine continues, just switching the 20 into 76.

Comment: I arrived at $\left|b_n-\dfrac53\right|=\left|\dfrac{6n+67}{3(3n^2-14)}\right|$. How do we get rid of the absolute value? The denominator isn't always positive for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: It is for $ n>10 $ which i assumed in the end.

Comment: But why do we need $n>10$? Isn't $n>2$ enough?

Comment: In these problems, you can even take $n $ as large as you want such as 2022 if it is convenient. here, $n=5 $ probably is sufficient  but for safe measure I took 10.

Comment: $3n^2-14$ is nonnegative for all $n\in\mathbb{N}>2$.

Comment: yes but remember we changed it into $ 3n^2-14n $ at some point so we can drop the $ n $, for that we need $ n=5 $, I chose to take 10